# Checkout failure SQLstate

Tags: error-handling, checkout, zend-db, magento2

I'm using magento 2.0.4 and PHP 7. 
At this point i'm desperate as my website needs to go live tomorrow.

**On checkout i get the next error :**
[picture here<---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2L2o.png)

```
> 
> 
> In my exception log i  have the next output : [2016-04-26 18:52:21]
> main.CRITICAL: Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: Report ID:
> webapi-571fb8e513432; Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
> violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'O-16-04-000014-1' for key
> 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO
> `sales_order` (`state`, `status`, `protect_code`,
> `shipping_description`, `is_virtual`, `store_id`, `customer_id`,
> `base_discount_amount`, `base_grand_total`, `base_shipping_amount`,
> `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_subtotal`, `base_tax_amount`,
> `base_to_global_rate`, `base_to_order_rate`, `discount_amount`,
> `grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`,
> `store_to_base_rate`, `store_to_order_rate`, `subtotal`, `tax_amount`,
> `total_qty_ordered`, `customer_is_guest`, `customer_note_notify`,
> `customer_group_id`, `quote_id`, `base_shipping_discount_amount`,
> `base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `base_total_due`,
> `shipping_discount_amount`, `subtotal_incl_tax`, `total_due`,
> `weight`, `increment_id`, `applied_rule_ids`, `base_currency_code`,
> `customer_email`, `customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`,
> `customer_middlename`, `customer_taxvat`, `discount_description`,
> `global_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `remote_ip`,
> `shipping_method`, `store_currency_code`, `store_name`,
> `total_item_count`, `customer_gender`,
> `discount_tax_compensation_amount`,
> `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount`,
> `shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount`,
> `base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt`,
> `discount_tax_compensation_invoiced`,
> `base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced`,
> `discount_tax_compensation_refunded`,
> `base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded`, `shipping_incl_tax`,
> `base_shipping_incl_tax`, `gift_message_id`, `delivery_date`) VALUES
> (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
> ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
> ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2016-04-19') in
> /data/sites/web/versdiversbe/www/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194
> Stack trace:
> #0 /data/sites/web/versdiversbe/www/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139):
> Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception))
> #1 /data/sites/web/versdiversbe/www/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(163):
> Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Exception))
> #2 /data/sites/web/versdiversbe/www/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #3 /data/sites/web/versdiversbe/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #4 /data/sites/web/versdiversbe/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
> #5 /data/sites/web/versdiversbe/www/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
> #6 {main} [] []
```

Anyone please an idea what i can do or check or how i can continue trouble shooting?

**Things i have done :**

- disabled every module that i have
- redeployed static content
- Checked php.ini settings
- Checked tax rates for double entries backend
- checked database for sales_sequence tables

**Know that**

- i use Php 7.0
- i use phpmyadmin 4.5
- I'm using a shared host at the moment
- I have limited knowledge of PHP coding

**UPDATES**

So now i get to the order confirmation page BUT i do not get a confirmation mail. It seems that the server has internal problems to reach the xml files

**UPDATES 2**

I keep having 'order confirmation mail was not sent' then i press send mail (in the backend on the order view) and it says 'order confirmation mail was sent' but it is not. Hmmn

Comment: So now i get to the order confirmation page BUT i do not get a confirmation mail. I think i still have the same problem but the custom registration fields that i added force the orrder

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting orders (actual orders, not order queue) from the cron_schedule in the database and putting my website 'asynchronous sending' on disabled